# Очистить лишние пробелы при отправке формы

Tags: php

Очищаю лишние пробелы при отправке формы функцией `trim()`, но если юзер введет `alt+255` то это не прокатит, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Сделайте регуляркой.

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = preg_repace("/\s+/si", "", $text);
```

Comment: только /^\s+|\s+$/si

Comment: нам нужно удалить все пробелы) 
Но про функционал трима я забыл) так что поддерживаю)